# error CS0619: `UnityEngine.RuntimePlatform.WindowsWebPlayer'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a new user trying Unity, and forgive me if this is a dumb question that can easily be solved with a single button, but I have been pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I keep getting these errors. Here is a screenshot:

> Assets/Plugins/Uniject/impl/UnibillUnityUtil.cs(74,25): error CS0619: `UnityEngine.RuntimePlatform.OSXDashboardPlayer` is obsolete: `Dashboard widget on Mac OS X export is no longer supported in Unity 5.4+.`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As the error states [`RuntimePlatform.OSXDashboardPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.OSXDashboardPlayer.html) as well as [`RuntimePlatform.OSXWebPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.OSXWebPlayer.html) and [`RuntimePlatform.WindowsWebPlayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.WindowsWebPlayer.html)) are obsolete and were removed in Unity version 5.4.0. If you still need them you will have to use an older version of Unity.

---

In general I would simply remove those entries from the list. Rather see the full list of available [`RuntimePlatform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RuntimePlatform.html) and you will see that others are missing now (the Linux ones)

```
public static List<RuntimePlatform> PCControlledPlatforms = new List<RuntimePlatform>()
{
    OSXEditor,     // In the Unity editor on macOS.
    OSXPlayer,     // In the player on macOS.
    WindowsPlayer, // In the player on Windows.
    WindowsEditor, // In the Unity editor on Windows.
    LinuxPlayer,   // In the player on Linux.
    LinuxEditor    // In the Unity editor on Linux.
}
```

---

However, one can see that [Uniject](https://github.com/banderous/Uniject) seems to be last updated 6 years ago ... so the probability that it is still working in newer Unity versions is quite low.

And also [unibill](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/add-ons/services/billing/unibill-5767) dosen't exist anymore so it is very probably not compatible with newer Unity versions.